# Ansible loop based on fact to Restart Kafka Connector Failed Tasks

Tags: apache-kafka, ansible, apache-kafka-connect

Here I want to restart Kafka Connect tasks if they are in failed state using ansible-playbook, I have fetched connector tasks state using 'set_fact'
I want to create a loop over collected facts to restart Kafka Connector Tasks using connector name and task id.

```
  tasks:
    - name: Gethering Connector Names
      uri:
        url: "{{scheme }}://{{ server }}:{{ port_no }}/connectors"
        user: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        method: GET
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 200
      register: conn_stat
    - name: Checking for Connector status
      uri:
        url: "{{scheme }}://{{ server }}:{{ port_no }}/connectors/{{ abc_conn_name }}/status"
        user: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        method: GET
        force_basic_auth: yes
      loop: "{{ conn_name }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: abc_conn_name
      vars:
        conn_name: "{{ conn_stat.json }}"
      register: conn_stat_1
    - name: Gethering Failed task id
      set_fact:
        failed_connector_name_task_id: "{{ conn_stat_1 | json_query('results[].json[].{name: name ,id: [tasks[?state == `RUNNING`].id [] | [0] ]}')  }}"
    - name: Failed connector name with tasks id
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var:  failed_connector_name_task_id
```

Getting below values from fact, which I need to push into loop

```
        "failed_connector_name_task_id": [
            {
                "id": [
                    0
                    1
                ],
                "name": "test-connector-sample"
            },
            {
                "id": [
                    0
                    1
                ],
                "name": "confluent-connect"
            },
            {
                "id": [
                    0
                    1
                    2
                ],
                "name": "confluent-test-1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "changed": false
}
```

value need to be posted

```
    - name: Restart Connector Failed tasks 
      uri:
        url: "{{scheme }}://{{ server }}:{{ port_no }}/connectors/**{{name of connector}}**/tasks/**{{task ID}}**/restart"
        user: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        method: POST
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 200
      register: conn_stat
```

**name of connector**,
**task ID** want to use in loop.

In above I need to setup loop for tasks.
As we can see above connector 'confluent-test-1' have three tasks in failed state, so it need to be iterate three times with task 'confluent-test-1'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical case where you want to use subelements, either through the aforementioned [filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-objects-and-subelements) or [lookup](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/subelements_lookup.html). Here is an example using the filter

```yaml
    - name: Restart Connector Failed tasks 
      uri:
        url: "{{scheme }}://{{ server }}:{{ port_no }}/connectors/{{ item.0.name }}/tasks/{{ item.1 }}/restart"
        user: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        method: POST
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 200
      loop: "{{ failed_connector_name_task_id | subelements('id', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

References worth to read:

- [ansible loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html)
- [subelements filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#combining-objects-and-subelements)

---

You can actually remove your last unnecessary `set_fact` task with e.g. the following construct:

```yaml
    - name: Restart Connector Failed tasks
      vars:
        failed_connector_name_task_id: "{{ conn_stat_1 | json_query('results[].json[].{name: name ,id: [tasks[?state == `RUNNING`].id [] | [0] ]}') }}"
      uri:
        url: "{{scheme }}://{{ server }}:{{ port_no }}/connectors/{{ item.0.name }}/tasks/{{ item.1 }}/restart"
        user: "{{ username }}"
        password: "{{ password }}"
        method: POST
        force_basic_auth: yes
        status_code: 200
      loop: "{{ failed_connector_name_task_id | subelements('id', skip_missing=True) }}"
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am not so Pro at Ansible, could you please explain a bit of.

Comment: I think the explanation will be more than clear if you click on the second link I gave above. There is an example that almost match your current data structure and will show you how the list of dicts containing each a list of values is transformed in a list of lists where element 0 is the current dict in the original list and element 1 the subelement from the list inside your dict.

Comment: Thanks this is working perfectly as needed, just on query want to invoke when condition if ('id')  have value else skip the task, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Which id values do you want to process ?

Comment: I want to invoke when condition, if there is some value on 'item.1' else skip the task.
when ---                 "id": [
                ],

Now used this -  when: item.1|string  != 'None'

Comment: Your example data cannot generate null values in `item.1` from my above proposition. Do you have elements in your input list where `id` is missing or empty? If yes, my latest edit should fix the issue.